# How root.render treats values written inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i am improving myself in react so please help me to find it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));

root.render(
    <>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </>
);
```

I want to know if we write HTML-Like thing in direct in root.render then what it will be treated as JSX or HTML ??

Because When i'm doing this:

```
root.render(
    <>
        React.createElement("h1",{},"Hiii i am React Element !");
    </>
);
```

I am getting the this as a normal string in output as it is not the h1 element with content.

The main question is how root.render treat values which we write in that, is it just show the ReactElements which are converted into html OR it can also support the html. can we use <> </> in root.render or not because sometimes when writing html like code then it shows the right output but when writing react element in these fragments then its not working ?